# query with two classes Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a product class ["product"] and a class sales units ["unitsales"]. Where this class has a "pointer" -> idProduct to ["product"].

I make a query in ["unitsales"] and need to bring the description of the product through the pointer "idProduct"

How to return the same query using parse in Objective-C?

```
self.descriptionProduct = [query objectForKey: @ "description"];
```

[image: Class Unitsales][image: Class Product with description]

Comment: Have you looked at `includes`?

Comment: Yes, but when I seek the description, the information is null.  
 [query includeKey:@"idProduct"]; 
 ....
 unitsale.descProduct = [object objectForKey:@"description"];